# How to improve peformance of extracting data code in Python and numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to implement missing point in DIC (Digital Image Correlation) results, which are missing due to destruction of material (photo).

[image]

I would like to put points (without values) for this area where it is missing. (native points from source data)

[image]

This code is part of my thesis and I would like to find those points which are missing due to destruction of material during tensile test. Data comming from DIC (Digital image correlation) method which measure strain on surface of specimen. When specimen suffer local failure DIC software cannot find pixel cluster and finaly missing points in this region.  I have over 30 specimens, each 50 frames. Total computation time for this data is about week.  Code shown bellow in version 1 - nothing to change on my computer is runing something about 4 minutes. Code in version 2 is shorten that: statement MARK1 from begin to end is commented, and Version 2 comment lines are uncommented, but still takes 3 minutes 45 seconds.

Input data: 
https://github.com/MarekSawicki/data/blob/master/022_0_29-03-2018_e11_45.csv

```
import numpy as np
import os
# changing of folder
os.chdir("D:/Marek/doktorat/Badania_obrobione/test")
# load data from file
data = np.genfromtxt('022_0_29-03-2018_e11_45.csv', delimiter=',',dtype='float64')
# separation of coordintates (points) and values (both floats64)
# data in format: list of points (X,Y) and list of values
points = data[1:,1:3]
values = data[1:,4]
#shifting coordinates to zero (points coordinates might be negative or offset from 0) (-x0)
points[:,0] -= min(points[:,0])
points[:,1] -= min(points[:,1])
#scale factor K_scale
k_scale=2
points[:,0:2] *= k_scale
# vector reshape
values=  np.reshape(values, [len(data)-1,1])
# sort the points to keep order in X direction 
# points X are assumed as points[:,0]
# points Y are assumed as points[:,1]
array1 = np.ascontiguousarray(points)
a_view = array1.view(dtype=[('', array1.dtype)]*array1.shape[-1])
a_view.sort(axis=0)
points_sorted = array1
# Start of processing points
# a and b are respectively X and Y limits 
a = np.int32(np.ceil(np.max(points[:,0])))+1
b = np.int32(np.ceil(np.max(points[:,1])))+1
# length 1 unit array cluster
array2=np.empty((0,2))
for m in range(0,3):
    for n in range(0,3):
        array2=np.append(array2,[[m*.5,n*.5]],axis=0)
# initialization of variables
k=0 # searching limits
bool_array_del=np.zeros((9,1), dtype=bool) # determine which line should be deleted - bool type
# array4 is a container of values which meets criteria
array4=np.empty((0,2))
# array7 is output container
array7=np.empty((0,2))
# main loop of concerned code:
for i in range(0,a): # X wise loop, a is a X limit
    for i2 in range(0,b): # Y wise loop, a is a Y limit
        array3 = np.copy(array2) # creating a cluster in range (i:i+1,i2:i2+1, step=0.5)
        array3[:,0]+=i
        array3[:,1]+=i2
        # value container (each loop it should be cleaned)
        array4=np.empty((0,2))
        # container which determine data to delete (each loop it should be cleaned)
        bool_array_del = np.empty((0,1),dtype=bool)
        k=0 # set zero searching limits
# loop for searching points which meet conditions.
# I think it is the biggest time waster
#To make it shorter I deal with sorted points which allows me 
#to browse part of array insted of whole array 
#(that is why I used k parameter and if-break condition )
        for i3 in range(k,points_sorted.shape[0]):
            valx = points_sorted[i3,0]
            valy = points_sorted[i3,1]
            if valx>i-1:
                k=i3
            if valx>i+1.5:
                break
#this condition check does considered point has X and  coordinates is range : i-0.5:i+1.5
# If yes then append this coordinate to empty container (array4)
            if np.abs(valx-(i+.5))<=1:
                if np.abs(valy-(i2+.5))<=1:
                    array4=np.append(array4,[[valx,valy]],axis=0)
# (version 2)       break
# Then postprocessing of selected points container - array4. To determine - do all point out of array4 should are close enough to be deleted?
    if array4.shape[0]!=0:
# (version 2) pass
# begin(MARK1)
# round the values from array4 to neares .5 value
        array5 = np.round(array4*2)/2
# if value from array5 are out of bound for proper cluster values then shift it to the closest correct value
        for i4 in range(0,array5.shape[0]):
            if array5[i4,0]>i+1:
                array5[i4,0]= i+1
            elif array5[i4,0]<i:
                array5[i4,0]=i
            if array5[i4,1]>i2+1:
                array5[i4,1]=i2+1
            elif array5[i4,1]<i2:
                array5[i4,1]=i2
# substract i,i2 vector and double from value of array5 to get indices which should be deleted
        array5[:,0]-=i
        array5[:,1]-=i2
        array5*=2
# create empty container with bool values - True - delete this value, False - keep
        array_bool1=np.zeros((3,3), dtype=bool)
        for i5 in range(0,array5.shape[0]):
# below condition doesn't work - it is too rough
            #array_bool1[int(array5[i5,0]),int(array5[i5,1])]=True
# this approach works with correct results but I guess it is second the biggest time waster.
            try: 
                array_bool1[int(array5[i5,0]),int(array5[i5,1])]=True
                array_bool1[int(array5[i5,0]+1),int(array5[i5,1]-1)]=True
                    array_bool1[int(array5[i5,0]+1),int(array5[i5,1])+1]=True
                    array_bool1[int(array5[i5,0]+1),int(array5[i5,1])]=True
                    array_bool1[int(array5[i5,0]-1),int(array5[i5,1]+1)]=True
                    array_bool1[int(array5[i5,0]-1),int(array5[i5,1]-1)]=True
                    array_bool1[int(array5[i5,0]-1),int(array5[i5,1])]=True
                    array_bool1[int(array5[i5,0]),int(array5[i5,1]+1)]=True
                    array_bool1[int(array5[i5,0]),int(array5[i5,1]-1)]=True
                except: 
                    pass
# convert bool array to list
            for i6 in range(0,array_bool1.shape[0]):
                for i7 in range(0,array_bool1.shape[1]):
                    bool_array_del=np.append(bool_array_del,    [[array_bool1[i6,i7]]],axis=0)
# get indices where bool list (unfotunatelly called bool_array_del) is true
            result= np.argwhere(bool_array_del)
            array6=np.delete(array3,result[:,0],axis=0)
# append it to output container
            array7=np.append(array7,array6,axis=0)
# if nothing is found in loop for searching points which meet conditions append full cluster to output array
# end(MARK1)
        else:
            array7=np.append(array7,array3,axis=0)
```

This code gives me satisfactionary results for version 1 (Fig 3) and acceptable results for version 2.(Fig 4)

[image]

[image]

I am new in python and numpy. Could you tell me what I can do better to speed up my code? I thought about switch to panda

Comment: This seems better suited for Code Review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. That said, you may find some utility with JIT compilation via `numba`: http://numba.pydata.org/

Comment: Also, if you provide a sample of your `022_0_29-03-2018_e11_45.csv` file, we could then be able to run it ourselves and see where the bottlenecks are.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will ask as well at codereview.stackexchange.com.
I am just looking through numba. I have added   `022_0_29-03-2018_e11_45.csv` to my github repository.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, Jordan Singer suggest very convinient solution - use JIT compilation via numba.
Time reduction is from 4 minutes to 4-5 seconds. From the other hand I was forced to not use `np.append`, but I used fix lenght zeros array and then delete zeros from array.

Reworked code below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
from numba import jit
import time
start = time.time()

# creating array4 from previous code changed to function with JIT decorator
@jit(nopython=True)
def Numba_Function_array4(if1,if2,source):
    k=0 # set zero searching limits
    index=0 # browse index for output array
    rarray=np.zeros((10,2)) # fixed length output array
# loop for searching points which meet conditions.
# I think it is the biggest time waster - in fact is!
#To make it shorter I deal with sorted points which allows me 
#to browse part of array insted of whole array 
#(that is why I used k parameter and if-break condition )
    for i3 in range(k,source.shape[0]):
        valx = source[i3,0]
        valy = source[i3,1]
        if valx>if1-1:
            k=i3
        if valx>if1+1.5:
        break
#this condition check does considered point has X and  coordinates is range : i-0.5:i+1.5
# If yes then append this coordinate to empty container (array4)
    if np.abs(valx-(if1+.5))<=1:
        if np.abs(valy-(if2+.5))<=1:
            rarray[index,:] = [valx,valy]
            index+=1
    return rarray

# changing of folder
os.chdir("D:/Marek/doktorat/Badania_obrobione/test")
cwd = os.getcwd()
# load data from file
data = np.genfromtxt('022_0_29-03-2018_e11_45.csv', delimiter=',',dtype='float64')
# separation of coordintates (points) and values (both floats64)
# data in format: list of points (X,Y) and list of values
points = data[1:,1:3]
values = data[1:,4]
#shifting coordinates to zero (points coordinates might be negative or offset from 0) (-x0)
points[:,0] -= min(points[:,0])
points[:,1] -= min(points[:,1])
#scale factor K_scale
ks=2
points[:,0:2] *= ks
# vector reshape
values=  np.reshape(values, [len(data)-1,1])
# sort the points to keep order in X direction 
# points X are assumed as points[:,0]
# points Y are assumed as points[:,1]
array1 = np.ascontiguousarray(points)
a_view = array1.view(dtype=[('', array1.dtype)]*array1.shape[-1])
a_view.sort(axis=0)
Input_points_sorted = array1
# Start of processing points
# a and b are respectively X and Y limits 
a = np.int32(np.ceil(np.max(points[:,0])))+1
b = np.int32(np.ceil(np.max(points[:,1])))+1
# length 1 unit array cluster (step 0.5)
array2=np.empty((0,2))
for m in range(0,3):
    for n in range(0,3):
    array2=np.append(array2,[[m*.5,n*.5]],axis=0)
# array7 is output container
array7=np.empty((0,2))
# main loop of concerned code:
for i in range(0,a): # X wise loop, a is a X limit
    for i2 in range(0,b): # Y wise loop, a is a Y limit
        array3 = np.copy(array2) # creating a cluster in range (i:i+1,i2:i2+1, step=0.5)
        array3[:,0]+=i
        array3[:,1]+=i2
        # function which contail the most time consuming part of the code
        array4 = Numba_Function_array4(i,i2,Input_points_sorted)
        # container which determine data to delete (each loop it should be cleaned)
        bool_array_del = np.empty((0,1),dtype=bool)
        # because in function umba_Function_array4 I created fixed length array I have to delete from the end zeros which indicates empty index
        for i8 in range(9,-1,-1):
            if array4[i8,0]==0:
                array4=np.delete(array4,i8,axis=0)

# Then postprocessing of selected points container - array4. To determine - do all point out of array4 should are close enough to be deleted?
        if array4.shape[0]!=0: 
# round the values from array4 to neares .5 value
            array5 = np.round(array4*2)/2
# if value from array5 are out of bound for proper cluster values then shift it to the closest correct value
            for i4 in range(0,array5.shape[0]):
                if array5[i4,0]>i+1:
                    array5[i4,0]= i+1
                elif array5[i4,0]<i:
                    array5[i4,0]=i
                if array5[i4,1]>i2+1:
                    array5[i4,1]=i2+1
                elif array5[i4,1]<i2:
                    array5[i4,1]=i2
# substract i,i2 vector and double from value of array5 to get indices which should be deleted
            array5[:,0]-=i
            array5[:,1]-=i2
            array5*=2
# create empty container with bool values - True - delete this value, False - keep
            array_bool1=np.zeros((3,3), dtype=bool)
            for i5 in range(0,array5.shape[0]):
                try: 
                    array_bool1[int(array5[i5,0]),int(array5[i5,1])]=True
                    array_bool1[int(array5[i5,0]+1),int(array5[i5,1]-1)]=True
                    array_bool1[int(array5[i5,0]+1),int(array5[i5,1])+1]=True
                    array_bool1[int(array5[i5,0]+1),int(array5[i5,1])]=True
                    array_bool1[int(array5[i5,0]-1),int(array5[i5,1]+1)]=True
                    array_bool1[int(array5[i5,0]-1),int(array5[i5,1]-1)]=True
                    array_bool1[int(array5[i5,0]-1),int(array5[i5,1])]=True
                    array_bool1[int(array5[i5,0]),int(array5[i5,1]+1)]=True
                    array_bool1[int(array5[i5,0]),int(array5[i5,1]-1)]=True
                except: 
                    pass
# convert bool array to list
            for i6 in range(0,array_bool1.shape[0]):
                for i7 in range(0,array_bool1.shape[1]):
                    bool_array_del=np.append(bool_array_del,[[array_bool1[i6,i7]]],axis=0)
# get indices where bool list (unfotunatelly called bool_array_del) is true
            result= np.argwhere(bool_array_del)
            array6=np.delete(array3,result[:,0],axis=0)
# append it to output container
            array7=np.append(array7,array6,axis=0)
# if nothing is found in loop for searching points which meet conditions append full cluster to output array
        else:
            array7=np.append(array7,array3,axis=0)
    end = time.time()
    print("Elapsed (after compilation) = %s" % (end - start))
    print("Done!")
```

Thanks again Jordan, problem solved!